# Using a txt file to display links with php

Tags: php

I am trying to display a links using php and txt file.

My Text file (text.txt)

```
Spiderman, www.spiderman.com
See No Evil, www.seenoevil.com
```

My php code so far (index.php);

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Reading from text files</title>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$f = fopen("text.txt", "r");

// Read line by line until end of file
while (!feof($f)) { 

// Make an array using comma as delimiter
   $arrM = explode(",",fgets($f)); 

// Write links (get the data in the array)
   echo "<li><a href='http://" . $arrM[1] . "'>" . $arrM[0]. "</a></li>"; 

}

fclose($f);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Error I keep getting when I run index.php. This is what the browser displays; 
[image: Error]

Comment: Looks like PHP is not installed (or not processing the file for another reason) and you see pure HTML

Comment: What is the solution? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you opened the index.php directly in a browser. There is no error in this code. Try run it in the proper way .that is  (localhost/yourDirectory/index.php)

Comment: I did. See @devaldcool's comment below. Its still giving the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If the browser gives you the output you have mentioned, this means that PHP has not been installed in your machine.Download and install [WAMP server](http://www.wampserver.com/en) to execute php scripts.
But, if php has been installed, you are not using the server address, i.e. `http://localhost/APP/`. `file:///C:/server/www/APP/` will not execute the php script.

Comment: I did. Now I am running it from `file:///C:/wamp/www/` but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [trim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) to remove the whitespace and the new line characters, then it should work fine, I just tried:

(Also, make sure the txt file doesn't have the utf-8 BOM)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Reading from text files</title>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$f = fopen("text.txt", "r");

// Read line by line until end of file
while (!feof($f)) { 

// Make an array using comma as delimiter
   $arrM = explode(",",fgets($f)); 

// Write links (get the data in the array)
   echo "<li><a href='http://" . trim($arrM[1]) . "'>" . trim($arrM[0]). "</a></li>"; 

}

fclose($f);
?>

</body>
</html>
```